# How compile on linux KNN CUDA?

Tags: c, linux, matlab, cuda, mex

Recently, I found  [knn CUDA](http://vincentfpgarcia.github.io/kNN-CUDA/) which is a group of Mex file that implement knn search  based on brute force, but in the README.md I have not found the way to compile this files in matlab using a linux distribution. I would appreciate ideas about how cope with this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of this kNN code :)

Back in 2008, the code was written using the Windows XP OS.
Since I provide the source code, you should be able to produce linux mex files.
In the ReadMe, I give the following command line for Windows :

`nvmex -f nvmexopts.bat knn_cuda_with_indexes.cu -I'C:\CUDA\include' -L'C:\CUDA\lib' -lcufft -lcudart -lcuda -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE`

Adapt it for your Linux distribution to generate your mex file.
A lot of things may have changed in 5 years so you may have to modify a few things.
However, the feedbacks I got from users indicate that it works just fine.

Try also to read about how to compile a CUDA code under Linux.
I guess NVidia provides a pretty nice tutorial.

Comment: I could compile kNN code in matlab and nsight. Here is the script that I used to compile in matlab. https://www.dropbox.com/s/626buoisasw2gg1/nvmex2.m

Comment: According to your [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5654017 "paper"). If the data is dim = 3 and n=65536 it is better use ANN library than Cuda or cublas knn. Could I increase n to higher values like 100000 or 200000 to speed it up?.

Answer (score 0):

You can also compile cuda+mex without nvmex. In MATLAB command, simply run the following two lines

```
>> !nvcc -c yourfile.cu -Xcompiler -fPIC -I$matlabroot/extern/include -I$matlabroot/toolbox/distcomp/gpu/extern/include
>> mex yourfile.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L$matlabroot/bin/glnxa64 -lcudart -lcufft -lmwgpu
```

replace `$matlabroot` with appropriate path. (Note that ! invoke system command in matlab)
The first line create object file and then `mex` links library.

You might have to modify your CUDA path to `/usr/loca/cuda-6.0/` or `/usr/local/cuda-YOUR_VERSION/`. Also for the cuda library `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` or `/usr/local/cuda/lib` Please check.

If you want to optimize your code simply put `-O3 -DNDEBUG`

```
>> !nvcc -O3 -DNDEBUG -c yourfile.cu -Xcompiler -fPIC -I$matlabroot/extern/include -I$matlabroot/toolbox/distcomp/gpu/extern/include
```

the library link command is same. 
Also please note that additional include path `-I$path` and library path `-L$path` or library `-l$library` might be required to suit your need.